# Alternative to Tiny MCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

Was wondering if anyone knows a good alternative to tinymce? I find that it sometimes has problems with AJAX infused content. And I've noticed that it seems a little slow when loading - I first see the textarea with the HTML-Markup and then it flashes and then I see the tiny interface.

wmd and markitup are not exactly what I am looking for - they are too rudimentary.

Is there any other good lightweight Javascript WYSIWYG Editor out there?

Thanks
Casper

Comment: This has been asked before, and before that again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800/whats-the-best-html-wysisyg-editor-available-to-web-developers-and-why Even though the accepted answer is tinyMCE, there are still a lot of other candidates in there. Try searching SO for "[javascript] wysiwyg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

peirix's comment was helpful.

Tried a couple of the suggested ones and apparently Tiny or FCK are the best of the crop.

--EDIT--
I found and liked: http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/

--EDIT 2012--
I have now moved back to a minimal/light weight tinyMCE installation using jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

What about [FCKeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/)?

Answer (score 3):

[CKEditor](http://www.ckeditor.com/) the new FCKEditor

Answer (score 3):

Personally my favorite as of late has been Quill.  Cleaner interface, simple documentation and overall cleaner code.

Here is their quick start:

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
```

```html
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.js"></script>
```

Website: 
https://quilljs.com/

Here is their playground:
https://quilljs.com/playground/

Finally, they do a great job of comparing themselves to other editors.

CKEditor, TinyMCE, Draft, ProseMirror and Trix:
https://quilljs.com/guides/comparison-with-other-rich-text-editors/

Answer (score 2):

[Attacklab](http://attacklab.net/) is used by StackOverflow, and myself soon enough. It's WYSIWYM, but still quite useful.

In the past, I have used [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/). There's actually two versions, one more basic than the other.

Answer (score 2):

[PunyMCE](http://www.moxieforge.net/overview.php?project_id=9&category_id=5) is a newer contender by the same guys that make TinyMCE. It's super lightweight and supports the important requirements of being themeable, plugin capable, and supports internationalization.

Answer (score 1):

FCKEditor is quite good, you can try that.