# What are the technologies used in the blogger types text editors?

Tags: html, text

How are the text editors in http://blogger.com , http://www.indiegogo.com/ , stackoverflow (which i am typing in now) and others made?

What are the technologies used in it and is there a ready made version, how do they sanitize data?

Comment: For implementations see [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164765/alternative-to-tiny-mce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of free WYSIWYG editors to choose from. See this article for a list:

http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/02/best-rich-text-editors-ready-to-use-in.html

CuteEditor:
http://cutesoft.net/Products/Default.aspx

TinyMCE:
http://www.tinymce.com/

CKEditor:
http://ckeditor.com/

There are also some editors available for purchase, like the RadEditor from Telerik for example. Some are better than others, but find the one that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use tiny mce (http://www.tinymce.com/). It's javascript, it's free and very flexible  to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get them ready-made as it were. They're usually pretty easy to install. They're called WYSIWYG editors. Try Tiny MCE, it's usually what I use. If you want something else:

http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors

They're usually written in Javascript. They don't sanitize data. You'll have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting in a good long word document, with lots of tables, fancy styling and images. Then you'll know how much sanitizing they do (tell me if you find one that does enough)